# S3 error document for static site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static-site

In the context of hosting a static SPA website, under what circumstances would the error document on S3 be served?

Is it something that should never happen if everything is set up correctly?

[image]

Comment: I know some people don't like the `/#/thing` path style, but it's well-suited to S3 hosting because you can use S3 redirect rules to ensure that a request for `/foo` gets redirected to `/#/foo` which is handled as `/` and causes `/index.html` to be returned so that the page is rendered as intended, rather than being handled as an error: https://serverfault.com/a/633571/153161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CustomErrorDocSupport.html

> Custom Error Document: You can optionally provide a custom error document that contains a user-friendly error message and additional help. You provide this custom error document as part of adding website configuration to your bucket. Amazon S3 returns your custom error document for only the HTTP 4XX class of error codes.

Lets say your website is example.com/ and a visitor goes to example.com/thispagedoesnotexist, if you setup your Error Document the visitor will get the 'friendly' error-page. As you can't control what a visitor of your website does. My personal opinion is to always setup a 'friendly' error-page as you can't control visitor behaviour to the detail.

Comment: In the case of a SPA (eg. React), it seems like we should use `index.html` as Error Document as routing is handled by source code in client app. (otherwise client-side routes will not work)

Comment: can, as mentioned I prefer to always have a backup :)

Comment: As much as you can protect your SPA against bad requests, nothing you do in your SPA can prevent your user from manually editing the address in the address bar of the browser. Thus bypassing all your SPA protections. Create a friendly error document :)